# how to remove white space in td tag?

Tags: php, html, html-table, removing-whitespace

I have a html table which i fill in php in a complex logic.
There are 4 foreach loops to fill the data.

Now this works fine but through the loops i get some whitespace in my  element.
The browser can display it fine, but as soon as I want to export this to a pdf, it will have some problems.

Anyone knows how to dismiss these whitespaces. Take a look at the image for more clarification:

[image]

Here's the code my variables which i echo out dont have any whitespaces. The problem also occur if give out echo "test";:

```
<div id="autoload-content"> 

    <table class="tg" >
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Montag</th>
            <th>Dienstag</th>
            <th>Mittwoch</th>
            <th>Donnerstag</th>
            <th>Freitag</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

    <?php
        $arrNoDoubleEntries = array();
        $totalFactorMo = 0;
        $stackIrregular = array();

        //displays all the different presencetypes
        foreach ($types as &$value) {
        ?>    
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($value->Name);?></td>

            <td>
            <?php //all Monday Childs 

            if ($value->Name == "Total"){
                echo ($totalFactorMo);
            }else{
                $childrenMonday = (Children::LoadPresence(1, $groupId));
                    foreach ($childrenMonday as &$child) {
                            foreach ($irregularPresence as &$irrugPrese){

                                if (($child->id == $irrugPrese->child_id) && ($monday >= $irrugPrese->datefrom) && ($monday <= $irrugPrese->dateto)){
                                    if ($irrugPrese->away == 1 && ($value->id == $child->presencetype)){                                
                                            echo("<s>".$child->fullName . " " . $child->factor."</s>");
                                            echo "<br />";
                                            array_push($stackIrregular, $child->id);
                                    }

                                    else{   

                                            if (($value->id == $irrugPrese->presencetype_id) AND (!(in_array($child->fullName + $irrugPrese->presencetype_id, $arrNoDoubleEntries)))){
                                                echo("<u>".$child->fullName . " " . $child->factor."</u>");
                                                echo "<br />";
                                                array_push($arrNoDoubleEntries, $child->fullName + $irrugPrese->presencetype_id);
                                                $totalFactorMo = $totalFactorMo + $child->factor;
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        if (!(in_array($child->id, $stackIrregular))) {
                            //prints the children which dont have some irregular Presences
                            if (!($child->presencetype == 1) && ($value->id == $child->presencetype)){
                                echo ($child->fullName . " " . $child->factor);
                                echo "<br />";
                                $totalFactorMo = $totalFactorMo + $child->factor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the code that generates the table …

Comment: Why not try looping over the table cells and trimming the whitespace with the [javascript trim method?](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

Comment: HTML normally ignores whitespace. Are you sure you do not add &nbsp; or some invisible space like &#160; or have CSS set to a pre-type whitespace handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case try to concatenate html and then show it like

```
<?php //all Monday Childs 
    $html = '';
        if ($value->Name == "Total"){
            $html .= ($totalFactorMo);
        }else{
            $childrenMonday = (Children::LoadPresence(1, $groupId));
                foreach ($childrenMonday as &$child) {
                        foreach ($irregularPresence as &$irrugPrese){

                            if (($child->id == $irrugPrese->child_id) && ($monday >= $irrugPrese->datefrom) && ($monday <= $irrugPrese->dateto)){
                                if ($irrugPrese->away == 1 && ($value->id == $child->presencetype)){                                
                                        $html .=("<s>".$child->fullName . " " . $child->factor."</s>");
                                        $html .= "<br />";
                                        array_push($stackIrregular, $child->id);
                                }

                                else{   

                                        if (($value->id == $irrugPrese->presencetype_id) AND (!(in_array($child->fullName + $irrugPrese->presencetype_id, $arrNoDoubleEntries)))){
                                            $html .=("<u>".$child->fullName . " " . $child->factor."</u>");
                                            $html .= "<br />";
                                            array_push($arrNoDoubleEntries, $child->fullName + $irrugPrese->presencetype_id);
                                            $totalFactorMo = $totalFactorMo + $child->factor;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    if (!(in_array($child->id, $stackIrregular))) {
                        //prints the children which dont have some irregular Presences
                        if (!($child->presencetype == 1) && ($value->id == $child->presencetype)){
                            $html .= ($child->fullName . " " . $child->factor);
                            $html .= "<br />";
                            $totalFactorMo = $totalFactorMo + $child->factor;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        echo $html;

        ?>
```

Comment: worked! Small modification i gave out: echo '<td>' . $html . '</td>';
And removed the <td> tag around the php

Answer (score 0):

You can trim spaces from the variable before displaying in the table like

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

or

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Comment: HTML will ignore normal spaces

Comment: What do u mean by normal spaces?

Comment: The %20 char is mostly ignored in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just strip all the white space before printing the value.

EG:

```
function cleanSpaces($text)  
{
  $text = preg_replace('/(xC2xA0/|&nbsp;)','',$text); //remove &nbsp;
  $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $loop_variable_value); //remove whitespace
  return $text;
}
```

Comment: This is only valid if there is actual whitespace in the string. What if it is stored in the DB with &nbsp; ?

Comment: my variable has no white spaces in it. I don't know where and why these spaces are created. It also happens if I give out something hardcoded.

Comment: Can you please share the value of your variable?